# sending email in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm getting an error when sending an email. the error is:

Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

I have enabled my google gmail account for less secure apps but I still get this error. I know somewhere you can add apps to have access to your gmail account but I don't know where that page is to add an app I keep getting the page where you can manage your app for your gmail account but I don't know where the page is to add that app could someone please help.

Comment: why would you use gmail smtp? why you dont use maitrap for dev and then use sendgird or any similar website for smtp service

Comment: could you show me how my mail config should look

Comment: the only change you need to do in mail.php is tge from field thats all, try to make a mailtrap.io and use the provided smtp credentials to test first

Answer (score 0):

Login in your gmail and go to this address
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
and Turn on `Access for less secure apps`